# JsonConvert.DeserializeObject not executing property setter

Tags: c#, json, json.net

Why is the setter on my `filename` property not executing when it is missing from the JSON?

How can I get the desired result if I can't use a setter?

See a simplified example below:

```
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace JsonDeserializeNulls
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var json1 = "{\r\n\t\"encoding\": \"base64\"\r\n}";
            var json2 = "{\r\n\t\"encoding\": \"base64\",\r\n\t\"filename\": null,\r\n}";

            var document1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Document>(json1);
            var document2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Document>(json2);

            Console.WriteLine(document1.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine(document2.ToString());

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    public class Document
    {
        public string Encoding { get; set; }

        private string _filename;
        public string Filename
        {
            get => _filename;
            set => _filename = string.IsNullOrEmpty(value) ? "NoFilenameSupplied" : value;
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
{"Encoding":"base64","Filename":null}

{"Encoding":"base64","Filename":"NoFilenameSupplied"}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a default constructor and initialize _filename to `NoFilenameSupplied`.

Edit:

The deserializer will call the default constructor first, setting _filename to `NoFilenameSupplied`. Even if the FileName property is missing in the JSON, this ensures that the property is set appropriately.

If you dont like adding the check to the setter, you can also do this:

```
[DefaultValue("")]
[JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore,DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Ignore)]
public string FileName { get; set; }
```

This will tell the JSON.NET deserializer to not set the property if the value in JSON is null or the default value of the type (string), which is null again. We are changing this by using the `DefaultValue` attribute making the deserializer think that the default value of that property is `String.Empty` and not null making the `NullValueHandling` and `DefaultValueHandling` work as expected.

Comment: Added explanation to the answer.

Comment: thanks. It's annoying that I have to set "NoFilenameSupplied" in two places though. I will have to create a constant file that both point to I guess!

Comment: @chris I have revised the answer to avoid this.

Answer (score 0):

`JsonConvert` will not call the setter, it simply directly loads data into the object. You are better off writing it this way:

```
public class Document
{
    public string Encoding { get; set; }

    public string Filename { get; set; }

    public string SafeFilename => string.IsNullOrEmpty(Filename) ? "NoFilenameSupplied" : Filename;

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this);
    }
}
```

Now you can use `SafeFilename` in your code to always get the value you want!

Comment: But this will never set the filename if a value is provided i.e. `{ "encoding": base64", "filename": "test" }` ?

Comment: It should work. The value will be deserialized into the Filename property. What makes you believe it won't work?

Comment: This wont work. Filename is a private property that wont be set by the deserializer.

Comment: There are couple of issues with this - Creates an unnecessary extra property. When you serialize this object that property will now exist in the json.

Comment: Depends on the use-case I guess, you can simply use a data annotation to make sure it is not serialized. I agree though, in an optimal architecture a separation between the `Model` and `ViewModel` would be present and the `ViewModel` would have this functionality.